# How to check if array contains a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have a json object which has an array property 'partners' like below:

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("578667b1bb14ca1c2773adaa"), 
    "customer" : null,  
    "created" : ISODate("2016-07-13T16:09:21.015+0000"), 
    "description" : "", 
    "subject" : "case 2", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(5), 
    "partners" : [
        ObjectId("57857d93038aacd81ef3ad55"), 
        ObjectId("57857d93038aacd81ef3ad56")
    ]
}
```

I would like to check if an element already exists on the partner array using the following code:

```
 _.includes(case_.partners, partner._id)
```

Just so u know I am using lodash for this but for some reason is not working and I have no clue why, anyone knows what is the problem here?

Comment: I just noticed something that partner._id returns '57857d93038aacd81ef3ad55' not like 'ObjectId("57857d93038aacd81ef3ad55")' maybe this is the problem for sure... how do I make it such a way that they are same format when it comes to check for duplicate elements on the array?

Comment: when it comes to insert a value into array this is how I insert:  case_.partners.push(partner._id); so it is inserting as 'ObjectId("57857d93038aacd81ef3ad55")' but when it comes to compare the partner._id comes as '57857d93038aacd81ef3ad55' and idk why

Comment: Please add the info you shared in comments to your question.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or embedded script with the problem, because it is unclear what `ObjectId` here means. You can't directly compare the outcome of `ObjectId('some string')` with `'some string'`: one is an Object, the other is a string, which always results in `false`.

Answer (score 0):

What I understanding, the `partners` sample you provided, is an javascript object, you should try to use primitive type value in the Json.

You can convert `ObjectId` to `String` by these way:

```
ObjectId("578667b1bb14ca1c2773adaa") + '';
```

or

```
ObjectId("578667b1bb14ca1c2773adaa").toHexString();
```

The Json object should be like this:

```
{ 
"_id" : "578667b1bb14ca1c2773adaa", 
"customer" : null,  
"created" : "2016-07-13T16:09:21.015+0000", 
"description" : "", 
"subject" : "case 2", 
"__v" : 5, 
"partners" : [
    "57857d93038aacd81ef3ad55", 
    "57857d93038aacd81ef3ad56"
]}
```

So the solution will be , convert Javascript object into Json object, and then compare them.

Comment: if I store partners id as '57857d93038aacd81ef3ad55' and not like 'ObjectId("57857d93038aacd81ef3ad55")' will I be able to populate partners when I show cases?

Comment: Yes,  I think so, also you can try _.contains instead of includes

Comment: _.contains says not a function

Comment: also when I do this:    case_.partners.push(partner._id); it automatically ads ObjectId(), how do I insert only the key without ObjectId()

Comment: _.contains, my typing mistake

Comment: _.contains is not longer used I guess on the latest version of lodash

Comment: i thought you were using underscore , sorry mate

Comment: any luck @mizlul ?